# How can i Filter "OU=Service account" from DistinguishedName in CSV file

Tags: powershell

[image]

i want this by import csv file and export to the file without the "ou=service account".......

Comment: Did you try anything yourself yet?

Comment: Import-CSV "C:\temp\temp.csv" | Where-Object {  $_."DistinguishedName" -notcontains "*,OU=Service Account,*" } |  Export-Csv "C:\temp\$date-$domain.csv" -NoTypeInformation

Comment: i tried it but no luck

Answer (score 0):

Your code is very close!

The only thing is that the `-notcontains` operator is meant for finding elements in an **array** and should not be used on single strings.
The same goes for `-contains`, `-in`, `-notin`. All of these work on arrays.

What should work is using the `-notmatch` regex operator.

<sup>Because this is regex, you should be aware that the string to search can hold characters that have special meaning in regex, like the dot. In your case, there is no such character, but if there were, you need to perform a `[regex]::Escape()` on the string to search for.</sup>

```
Import-CSV "C:\temp\temp.csv" | 
    Where-Object { $_.DistinguishedName -notmatch ",OU=Service Account," } | 
    Export-Csv "C:\temp\$date-$domain.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Or by using the `-notlike` operator with wildcards `*` on either side of the string:

```
Import-CSV "C:\temp\temp.csv" | 
    Where-Object { $_.DistinguishedName -notlike "*OU=Service Account,*" } | 
    Export-Csv "C:\temp\$date-$domain.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

The confusion with `-contains` or `-notcontains` is easy to make, because a string object has a `.Contains()` method and yes, that **does** work on the string you provide.
Therefore, this should also work for you:

```
Import-CSV "C:\temp\temp.csv" | 
    Where-Object { !($_.DistinguishedName.Contains(",OU=Service Account,")) } | 
    Export-Csv "C:\temp\$date-$domain.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Hope that helps

P.S. You do not show what is inside the `$date` variable, but as long as this does not have invalid filename characters like `\` or `:` it should be fine.