# How can i Filter “OU=Service account” from column DistinguishedName from a CSV file attached : powershell

Tags: powershell

i tried below command but its not working for me,
i need help to filter column by search `OU=service account`.
ran for full value of cell (`CN=k kk,OU=Service Account,DC=lucknow,DC=unicef,DC=com`) its working fine

```
Import-CSV "C:\temp\temp.csv" | Where-Object { $_."DistinguishedName" -notcontains "CN=k kk,OU=Service Account,DC=lucknow,DC=unicef,DC=com"}|  Export-Csv "C:\temp\Filter.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

But NOT working below Script for value: (`OU=Service Account`) >>>> i need to be filter column which contains (`OU=Service Account`)

```
Import-CSV "C:\temp\temp.csv" | Where-Object { $_."DistinguishedName" -notcontains "*,OU=Service Account,*"}|  Export-Csv "C:\temp\Filter.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: GivenName sn SamAccountName DistinguishedName isdisabled ObjectType
h  h CN=h,CN=Users,DC=lucknow,DC=unicef,DC=com Yes Non privileged
i  i CN=i,CN=Users,DC=lucknow,DC=unicef,DC=com no Non privileged
j jj j CN=j,CN=Users,DC=lucknow,DC=unicef,DC=com no Privilege
  krbtgt CN=krbtgt,CN=Users,DC=lucknow,DC=unicef,DC=com Yes Non privileged
k kk k CN=k kk,OU=Service Account,DC=lucknow,DC=unicef,DC=com no Non privileged
l ll l CN=l,OU=Service Account,DC=lucknow,DC=unicef,DC=com no Non privileged
m mm m CN=m mm,OU=Service Account,DC=lucknow,DC=unicef,DC=com no Non privileged

Comment: refer above file format in csv

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can i Filter "OU=Service account" from DistinguishedName in CSV file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61416161/how-can-i-filter-ou-service-account-from-distinguishedname-in-csv-file). The same question and I have just answered that.

Comment: @Theo same question by the same author.

Answer (score 0):

Read the docs.  -notcontains doesn't do what you think (although this is a very common point of confusion), and doesn't use wildcards.  I grant you that it works in the first case.  I think you want -notlike.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators